# Matrix Induced norms for when $q=p=\infty$ $q=p=1$ and $q = \infty$ while $p =1$

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, matrix-norms

The norm for our matrix is defined as:

$$
\|A\| = \max_{x\neq 0} \frac{\|A\pmb x\|_q}{\|\pmb x\|_p}
$$

I'm asked to "characterize" the matrix norm for various situations.

Here was my approach (you'll see in **Q3** that I noticed a flaw in my reasoning that probably invalidates my answers for **Q1** and **Q2**)

#### Q1 $q=p=\infty$

$$
\begin{align}
\|A\| &= \max_{x\neq 0} \frac{\|A\pmb x\|_1}{\|\pmb x\|_1}\\[10pt]
      &= \frac{\|(\pmb u \Sigma \pmb v^T)(a \pmb{\bar x})\|_1}{\|a \pmb{\bar x}\|_1}\\[10pt]
      &= \frac{|a|}{|a|} \frac{\|\pmb u \Sigma \pmb (v^T\pmb{\bar x})\|_1}{\|\pmb{\bar x}\|_1}\\
      &= \frac{\|\pmb u \Sigma(1))\|_1}{\| \pmb{\bar x}\|_1}\\
      &= \frac{\|\begin{pmatrix} \lambda_1 & 0 & \cdots & 0\end{pmatrix}\|_1}{\sum_{i=1}^n |{\bar x}_i |} \\
      &= \frac{|\lambda_1|}{\sum_{i=1}^n |{\bar x}_i |}
\end{align}
$$

#### Q2 $q=p=1$

Follow the same steps before except at the end we have:
$$
\frac{|\lambda_1|}{\max(\bar x_i)}
$$

#### Q3 $q=\infty$ and $p=1$

When thinking about question 3 I assumed that orienting vector $\pmb x$ didn't grow the norm in the denominator any more than moving the direction of *stretch* to the largest singular value...

Which then leaves me stumped on all $3$.

Any suggestions for how to approach the problem? I can probably just give a lower bound if there isn't a better way to go about it.

Comment: Look up the Krein-Milman Theorem.  Then characterize the extreme points of the unit ball of the two spaces.

Comment: We ended up going over it in class, I'll post up what I ended up turning in